# CKEditor - Link Dialog - Internal Links

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I need to be able to select internal pages for links. There is already a ["confirmed New Feature" ticket](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9806) on CKEditor's development site. It's slated for release in February. How can I retrofit this feature to the 4.0 release so I can take advantage of it before then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this [pull request](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/pull/9) satisfy your needs you can:

1. clone [ckeditor-dev](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev) repository,
2. fetch changes from patch author's repository,
3. merge his patch into 4.0 branch from ckeditor-dev,
4. use command line builder (`dev/builder/build.sh` - config is in `dev/builder/build-config.js`) to create CKEditor package.

But I would rather recommend you to wait for official patch. It's not ready yet, but for 90% will be in February.

Comment: When I read the code it appears that the the pages are a coded configuration and not a dynamic source. Is that correct? If so, is that what the official patch will be as well?

Comment: I haven't reviewed proposed patch yet, so I don't know how it works. But I anticipate that we'll somehow allow dynamic links data loading, because this is a common requirement.